# Accessing functions in another file

Tags: javascript

I have file1.js :

```
View = function(){

var privateprop;

this.method=function(){
...
}

}
```

and file 2 like this:

```
subView = new function(){
 var privateProp2;

this.method2= function(){

}

}
```

I want an instance of subView in file1.js
like:

```
var fileObj = new subView();
fileObj.method2();
```

can I access this directly ? I mean can I access classes(actually functions) defined in file2.js in file1.js directly? Dont we need any imports in Javascript?

Comment: Have you included both of these files as a `<script src="">`? Technically importing these via HTML is the same as pasting the content directly in the HTML, so yes - this would work if they were both imported.

Comment: What you think have you tried?
`<script type='file2.js'/>
<script type='file1.js'/>` working?

Comment: Refer this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want to use your JS in HTML: just include both files in your HTML file like this:

```
<script src="file2.js"></script> 
<script src="file1.js"></script>
```